# Find the laurent series of the function $f(z) = \frac{1}{(z+i)(z-5i)}$ which is valid in the annulus where $1 < |z| < 5$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

> Find the laurent series of the function $$f(z) = \frac{1}{(z+i)(z-5i)}$$ which is valid in the annulus where $1 < |z| < 5$

This is where I'm at currently. I'm not sure if this is the correct way of going about answering this:

$$\frac{1}{(z+i)(z-5i)}$$

$$= \frac{-1}{6i(z+i)} + \frac{1}{6i(z-5i)}$$

$$= \frac{i}{6(z+i)} + \frac{-i}{6(z-5i)}$$

**Partial fraction 1:**

$$\frac{i}{6(z+i)} = \frac{i}{6z+6i} = \frac{i}{6z(1+\frac{i}{z})} = \frac{i}{6z} \cdot \frac{1}{(1-(-\frac{i}{z}))}$$

$1 < |z|$, so:  $$|-\frac{i}{z}| = \frac{1}{|z|} < 1$$

$$\frac{i}{6(z+i)} = \frac{i}{6z} \cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-\frac{i}{z})^n = \frac{1}{6} \cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-\frac{i}{z})^{n+1}$$

**Partial fraction 2:**

$$\frac{-i}{6(z-5i)} = \frac{-i}{6z-30i} = \frac{-i}{-30i(1-\frac{z}{5i})} = \frac{1}{30(1-\frac{z}{5i})} =\frac{1}{30} \cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{5i}}$$

$|z| < 5$, so:  $$|\frac{z}{5i}| = \frac{|z|}{5} < 1$$

$$-\frac{i}{6(z-5i)} = \frac{1}{30i} \cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{z}{5i})^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{z}{5})^n \cdot (\frac{1}{i})^{n+1}$$

So

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{6} \cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-\frac{i}{z})^{n+1} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{z}{5})^n \cdot (\frac{1}{i})^{n+1}$$

$$ = \frac{1}{6} [ \sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}-(\frac{z}{i})^{2n+1} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{i}{z})^{2n}] + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{z}{5})^n \cdot (\frac{1}{i})^{n+1}$$

Valid in the annulus $1< |z| < 5$

(Apologies if there are any small mistakes)

If this is the final result, I imagine it could be simplified further.

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: I don't see h9w you get three sums at the end. It seems like you've artificially broken out the even and odd negative terms, which seems unnecessary.  Also, you shouldn't have $(\frac iz )^{2n}$ in a Laurent series - everything should be a coefficient times $z^k,$ here $i^{2n}z^{-2n}.$

Comment: In the line $\frac{i}{6(z+i)}=\cdots,$ you seem to have substituted $$\frac iz(-\frac{i}z)^n=(-\frac{i}z)^{n+1},$$ which is wrong - you need to add a minus sign to the right side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly your argument, but cleaned up and expressed as an actual Laurent series.

It is probably easier to do this first for $g(w)=f(iw).$ Then we don't have to keep track of all those $i$ values just yet, staying in the real coefficients.

We get $$g(w)=\frac1{(1+w)(5-w)}=\frac16\left(\frac1{1+w}+\frac1{5-w}\right)$$ and you get, for $|w|>1,$

$$\frac1{1+w}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}(-1)^{n+1}w^n$$

and:

$$\frac1{5-w}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{w^n}{5^{n+1}},$$ for $|w|<5.$

So: $g(w)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} b_nw^n$ where:

$$b_n=\begin{cases}\frac16(-1)^{n+1}&n<0\\
\frac16\frac{1}{5^{n+1}}&n\geq0
\end{cases}$$

Now $f(z)=g(-iz).$ So you get $f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_nz^n$ where $$a_n=(-i)^n b_n=\begin{cases}-\frac{i^n}6&n<0\\ \frac16\frac{(-i)^n}{5^{n+1}}&n\geq 0
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your response(s)! Hope you don't mind me asking, but I'm just curious on how to go from  $\frac{1}{6}(-1)^{n+1}(-i)^n$ to $-\frac{i^n}{6}$ for the coefficients $b_n$ when $n < 0$.

Comment: ...when substituting $-iz$ into $g(w)$. Sorry for not wording that very well.

Comment: $$(-1)^{n+1}(-i)^n=(-1)(-1)^n(-i)^n=(-1)((-1)(-i))^n=-i^n.$$ @Anonymous73648

Comment: Tysm! :D (Also, cool profile pic imo)